# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap popover with D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I would like to use a Twitter Bootstrap tooltip with D3.js. Here's an example of the tooltip I am trying to integrate with D3:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaZK5/1/

As a minimal working example, I'm trying to use this tooltip on some text:

```
  svg.append('text')
    .attr('x', 100)
    .attr('y', 100)
    .attr('class', 'pop-div')
    .html('<a href="#" class="myid" rel="popover" >click me</a>')
```

Unfortunately, the tooltip does not work on my text. How can I get this tooltip to work with D3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put html in a svg `text` element, but you can use the [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to do this.

I have not tested this, but something like this should work:

```
svg.append('svg:foreignObject')
   .attr('width', ...)
   .attr('height', ...)
   .append('xhtml:div')
   .attr('class', 'pop-div')
   .html('<a href="#" class="myid" rel="popover" >click me</a>')
```

**However**, IE doesn't support `foreignObject`, so you might want to solve it differently, e.g. by not putting the tooltip in svg, but in a html layer.

I use [d3-tip](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) in my d3.js project.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried you solution, but it did not seem to work. I don't see any text. I saw d3-tip, but couldn't figure out how to implement a scrolling tooltip.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is my first time using jsfiddle, so I've attempted to start this here: http://jsfiddle.net/E4hXh/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/pUhG3/ (Popover inside svg by use of `foreignObject`). There are some issues with positioning the popover in this fiddle, but I'm sure you can solve them.

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried to see if I could figure out the positioning, but not success yet. Unsure if I need to adjust something with D3 or bootstrap css. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2RCu3/).

Created this fiddle using this [<kbd>**link**</kbd>](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579).

Showing the use of `d3-tooltip`.

Firstly, here's the [**`link`**](http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js) for `d3-tooltip`.

Load this js file once d3 is loaded.

Here's the function for `d3-tooltip`.

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "Frequency: " + d.frequency + "";
  })
```

Then call the tooltip function once `svg` element is created.

Like this -

```
svg.call(tip);
```

Note : `svg` is the variable defined in `d3` i.e., the container of the graph.

There you go. Clean and nice tooltip which can easily be customized using `css` like this.

```
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps :)